# How to target a child input's placeholder in Tailwind CSS?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm currently working on a project and I'm trying to convert a CSS style that targets the `::placeholder` pseudo-element into Tailwind CSS, but I'm facing some challenges. Here's the CSS code I'm trying to convert:

```
//CSS Code 

input::Placeholder{}
```

In Tailwind CSS, I'm familiar with how to select child elements using [&>(Child Element)]. However, I'm unsure about how to target pseudo-elements like ::placeholder in Tailwind CSS.

As i am thinking `[&>input]:placeholder:(target)` ?

Could someone please assist me in converting the ::placeholder selector into Tailwind CSS classes? I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to achieve the same styling for ::placeholder using Tailwind. Thank you!

I attempted to convert the CSS ::placeholder into Tailwind CSS, seeking a specific Tailwind solution for styling input placeholders effectively.

Comment: this already works: `[&>input]:placeholder:text-red-500`

Answer (score -1):

In Tailwind CSS, there isn't a direct class for targeting the ::placeholder pseudo-element like you would in traditional CSS. However, you can achieve similar styling effects for input placeholders by using utility classes to style the input element itself.

Here's how you can style input placeholders effectively using Tailwind CSS:

```
<input
  class="border border-gray-300 py-2 px-3 rounded-md placeholder-gray-400 text-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:border-blue-500"
  type="text"
  placeholder="Enter your text here"
>
```